# Razor if statement inside HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

Why I can do that:

```
 @Code
   Dim styleVisible As String = if(Model.IndicateurAchatPeriodique,"block","none")
End Code
        <div id="@sectionDCAId" style="display:@styleVisible">...
```

but not that:

```
<div id="@sectionDCAId" style="display:@If(Model.IndicateurAchatPeriodique,"block","none")">
```

I just moved the if instruction inside the HTML but it throw an error. Why the compiler can't understand it?
I don't need solutions, just an explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler seems to have problems with inline VB.NET Ifs.  Not sure if it is a bug or it just isn't quite that clever.  I know you haven't asked for a solution, but if you put an extra set of brackets in to help it then it will probably work - as in `@(If(Model.IndicateurAchatPeriodique,"block","none"))`

Comment: That's how I normally get around it so it does often work.  Can't guarantee it will in all cases

Comment: This should work. Here is the complete line `<div id="@sectionDCAId" style="display:@(If(Model.IndicateurAchatPeriodique,"block","none"))">Abc</div>`

Comment: The Razor compiler is pretty clever and can work out a lot of things intelligently, but it isn't perfect.  In this case, I think it is getting mixed up with the @If ... Then format of If and is expecting that.  It may be that when Razor was written, the developers weren't as familiar with VB.NET as C# and didn't consider this case so it may be a bug, or it may be that there is some technical consideration that means that it was done this way intentionally eg. because it could slow down the Razor parsing